# ocultar css en widget

Tags: css, wordpress

Tengo un widget en el sitio que funciona como un preview al hacer clic en un enlace. Tiene  la dimension de la pantalla del celular, por lo cual automaticamente se le agrega al contenido el menu responsive.

Quiero ocultar el siguiente css sólo en ese widget

```
 .mobile-menu-builder-customizer--container {
 display: none!important;
 }
```

Si aplicó este css eliminó el menú de todas mis páginas en vista normal y no es lo que quiero

Estoy intentando así pero no funciona

```
 <code><script>
   function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
 </script>


  <iframe name="main" style=" width: 100%;" mobile-menu-builder-customizer--container="
display: none!important;"
 src="https://example.com/blank"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this);" >

</iframe>
 </code>
```

Podran ayudarme?Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Quieres eliminar el css dentro del widget solo? ¿A qué afecta ese css? ¿Afecta a elementos que están en el interior del widget? La pregunta es un poco confusa, trata de explicarla más a fondo para que sea más fácil identificar el problema :)

Comment: Hola! Exacto. Edite mi pregunta, espero sea más clara. Afecta a todos los elementos dentro del widget ( es como pagina Mini)